# Running some Ajax code gave an undefined value in the console

Tags: javascript, ajax, pug

I have a gradation project to create a better website to handle student registrations.

I followed a youtube playlist to learn more about node.js and other packages, so when i run this code i get back an undefined value, any ideas why ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.delete-student').on('click', function(e){
    $target = $(e.target);
    const id = $target.attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
      type:'DELETE',
      url: '/students/'+id,
      success: function(response){
        alert('Deleting Student');
        window.location.href='/';
      },
      error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Error

[image: error]

PUG code:

```pug
extends layout

block content
h1= student.first_name + " " + student.last_name
hr

.container
    h4 More infomation:
    ul.list-group
        li.list-group-item  First name    : #{student.first_name}
        li.list-group-item  Last name     : #{student.last_name}
        li.list-group-item  Parents Email : #{student.parentEmail}
        li.list-group-item  School        : #{student.school}

hr
h5 School : #{student.school}
hr 
a.btn.btn-default(href='/student/edit/'+student._id) Edit
a.btn.btn-danger.delete-student(href='#',data.id=student._id) Delete
```

Comment: _"so when i run this code..."_ where? In your browser or via node? Also, what does _"get back"_ mean? What **exactly** are you seeing and where?

Comment: I run this code on a browser(chrome), i meant by "get back" is that when i run the function the code logs "undefined" in the chrome console.

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of your console when you run this code?  It would help to determine whether it's your browser emiting the result of the expression or the browser emitting the result of a `console.log()`.

Comment: @KF3 nice screenshot.  This should help folks figure out what's up. Just a note that in order to keep the question self contained, it's best to just inline the screenshot right into the question.  This way, someone googling in will see the entire question even when that screenshot site goes outta business. (And yeah...folks don't like clicking on random links).

Comment: @Phil, my apologies, not really a jQuery expert (or advocate). Thanks for the check; comment deleted.

Comment: What does your HTML look like. `$target.attr('data-id')` is returning `undefined`

Comment: Questions.  Does `e.target` exist in your click event handler? Did you mean to get the `target` attribute of the element that fired the event?

Comment: @ctt `target` is an event property. See https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: Ah. Gotcha @Phil.

Comment: i added a screenshot of the code, sorry i wrote it with PUG not HTML

Comment: @KF3 please include all code as text. Images are not appropriate. You can also view the generated HTML source code via your browser's _"View page source"_ option

Comment: @Phil Sorry i edited the post (first time posting :3)

Comment: @KF3 no worries. You're doing great btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update and *"real"* answer™

[PUG attributes](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html) are interpreted as-is so instead of

```
(href='#',data.id=student._id)
```

you should have

```
(href='#',data-id=student._id)
```

---

Assuming your `.delete-student` element is the same one having `data-id="..."`, alter your code to

```
$target = $(this)
```

jQuery automatically binds the element handling the bound event to the lexical scope of the event handler, ie `this`.

You might even want to change your selector to

```
$('.delete-student[data-id]')
```

to ensure there is definitely the required attribute present.

---

The issue with using `event.target` is that if the event originated further down the document hierarchy, `event.target` refers to the originally clicked element.

Consider this structure

```
<button class="i-really-want-clicks-on-me" data-id="required">
  <span>I'm the label</span>
</button>
```

If you bind an event handler on the `<button>` but click on the `<span>`, `event.target` will be the `<span>`.